# Ubuntu Server 11.10 on a LAN is refusing connections

Tags: 11.10

my ubuntu installation is on a LAN configured on it is email server, likewise-open, NFS, autofs. Sometimes it refuses to ping other computers as well as refuse connections from other computers. What could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would try :

- firewall ( doubtful but still something to look )
- duplicate ip address ( ie, 2 computers with the same IP )
- check the ethernet cable, the switch. Cable can be faulty, as well as the switch, or the ethernet card.

I would also try to see when this occurs, how long it last, and if there is anything useful in log or in dmesg output. And try to see what was changed just before it started to fail.

Something that could help you is to setup nagios or smokeping.

Comment: I just blacklisted iptables. The computer now accepts connections to/from other computers. One thing that refuses to work again is ssh'ing or su'ing to a domain user account. This was working properly initially.